# How to get column-level permissions for materialized view?

Tags: postgresql

I have a materialized view in Postgres that I granted column-level `select` permissions on to a user:

```sql
grant select (id, description) on recent_sales_mv to alice
```

How could I write a query to see those *column-level* permissions reflected in the underlying system tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`information_schema.column_privileges`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-column-privileges.html):

> The view `column_privileges` identifies all privileges granted on columns to a currently enabled role or by a currently enabled role. There is one row for each combination of column, grantor, and grantee.

For some reason it seems like it works fine for tables and views but not for materialized views: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/U9qNo1Ss)

```sql
create role alice;

create table sales(
  id int generated always as identity primary key, 
  secret_column int, 
  description int,
  fin_date date);

create view public.recent_sales_v as 
  select * from sales where fin_date>now()-'1 week'::interval;
grant select (id, description) on recent_sales_v to alice;

create materialized view public.recent_sales_mv as 
  select * from sales where fin_date>now()-'1 week'::interval;
grant select (id, description) on recent_sales_mv to alice;

select * from information_schema.column_privileges 
  where table_schema='public'
  and not current_user=all(array[grantor,grantee]);
```

Notice it lists the view with `_v` suffix, but not the materialized view  with `_mv`:

| grantor | grantee | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | column_name | privilege_type | is_grantable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | alice | postgres | public | recent_sales_v | description | SELECT | NO |
| postgres | alice | postgres | public | recent_sales_v | id | SELECT | NO |

If you take a closer look at the definition of `column_privileges` it turns out it's simply because matviews are omitted when it fetches stuff from `pg_class`:

```sql
WHERE pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r'::"char", 'v'::"char", 'f'::"char", 'p'::"char"])
```

From [`pg_class.relkind`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html):

> `relkind` `char`
>
> `r` = ordinary table, `i` = index, `S` = sequence, `t` = TOAST table, `v` = view, **`m` = materialized view**, `c` = composite type, `f` = foreign table, `p` = partitioned table, `I` = partitioned index

So we're just missing `m`. Snatch the definition, add that in and you get your full view: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/RbJXh3sS)

| grantor | grantee | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | column_name | privilege_type | is_grantable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | alice | postgres | public | recent_sales_v | description | SELECT | NO |
| postgres | alice | postgres | public | recent_sales_mv | description | SELECT | NO |
| postgres | alice | postgres | public | recent_sales_mv | id | SELECT | NO |
| postgres | alice | postgres | public | recent_sales_v | id | SELECT | NO |

For completeness, here is the definition for `column_privileges` with matviews added, that you can use to get the info you need:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT u_grantor.rolname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS grantor,
    grantee.rolname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS grantee,
    current_database()::information_schema.sql_identifier AS table_catalog,
    nc.nspname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS table_schema,
    x.relname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS table_name,
    x.attname::information_schema.sql_identifier AS column_name,
    x.prtype::information_schema.character_data AS privilege_type,
        CASE
            WHEN pg_has_role(x.grantee, x.relowner, 'USAGE'::text) OR x.grantable THEN 'YES'::text
            ELSE 'NO'::text
        END::information_schema.yes_or_no AS is_grantable
   FROM ( SELECT pr_c.grantor,
            pr_c.grantee,
            a.attname,
            pr_c.relname,
            pr_c.relnamespace,
            pr_c.prtype,
            pr_c.grantable,
            pr_c.relowner
           FROM ( SELECT pg_class.oid,
                    pg_class.relname,
                    pg_class.relnamespace,
                    pg_class.relowner,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(pg_class.relacl, acldefault('r'::"char", pg_class.relowner)))).grantor AS grantor,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(pg_class.relacl, acldefault('r'::"char", pg_class.relowner)))).grantee AS grantee,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(pg_class.relacl, acldefault('r'::"char", pg_class.relowner)))).privilege_type AS privilege_type,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(pg_class.relacl, acldefault('r'::"char", pg_class.relowner)))).is_grantable AS is_grantable
                   FROM pg_class
                  WHERE pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r'::"char", 'v'::"char", 'm'::"char", 'f'::"char", 'p'::"char"])) pr_c(oid, relname, relnamespace, relowner, grantor, grantee, prtype, grantable),
            pg_attribute a
          WHERE a.attrelid = pr_c.oid AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
        UNION
         SELECT pr_a.grantor,
            pr_a.grantee,
            pr_a.attname,
            c.relname,
            c.relnamespace,
            pr_a.prtype,
            pr_a.grantable,
            c.relowner
           FROM ( SELECT a.attrelid,
                    a.attname,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(a.attacl, acldefault('c'::"char", cc.relowner)))).grantor AS grantor,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(a.attacl, acldefault('c'::"char", cc.relowner)))).grantee AS grantee,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(a.attacl, acldefault('c'::"char", cc.relowner)))).privilege_type AS privilege_type,
                    (aclexplode(COALESCE(a.attacl, acldefault('c'::"char", cc.relowner)))).is_grantable AS is_grantable
                   FROM pg_attribute a
                     JOIN pg_class cc ON a.attrelid = cc.oid
                  WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped) pr_a(attrelid, attname, grantor, grantee, prtype, grantable),
            pg_class c
          WHERE pr_a.attrelid = c.oid AND (c.relkind = ANY (ARRAY['r'::"char", 'v'::"char", 'm'::"char", 'f'::"char", 'p'::"char"]))) x,
    pg_namespace nc,
    pg_authid u_grantor,
    ( SELECT pg_authid.oid,
            pg_authid.rolname
           FROM pg_authid
        UNION ALL
         SELECT 0::oid AS oid,
            'PUBLIC'::name) grantee(oid, rolname)
  WHERE x.relnamespace = nc.oid AND x.grantee = grantee.oid AND x.grantor = u_grantor.oid AND (x.prtype = ANY (ARRAY['INSERT'::text, 'SELECT'::text, 'UPDATE'::text, 'REFERENCES'::text])) AND (pg_has_role(u_grantor.oid, 'USAGE'::text) OR pg_has_role(grantee.oid, 'USAGE'::text) OR grantee.rolname = 'PUBLIC'::name)
) AS column_privileges_but_with_matviews
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND NOT current_user=ALL(array[grantor,grantee]);
```